# Having trouble adding validation errors to ACF form

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF with WordPress and I have a form that I am trying to add a validation error to, but it doesn't appear to be working (I think I know why)...

**My code:**

```
function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field  ) {

    // Get the users numerical user id
    $user_id = str_replace('user_', '', $post_id);

    $value = sanitize_text_field($value);

    /** @noinspection PhpParamsInspection */
    $user_data = wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'user_email' => $value ) );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user_data ) ) {
        $wp_error = $user_data->get_error_message();
        $input = $field['prefix'] . '[' . $field['key'] . ']';
        acf_add_validation_error($input, $wp_error);
    }

    return $value;

}

add_filter('acf/update_value/key=field_5c121023e119f', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

As you may be able to tell I am attempting to update the users email address field (default WP one) based off the email provided by a user in an email field on a frontend ACF Form.

I then check to see if the update caused any errors and obviously if it did I want to add to the ACF validation errors, but it passers through successfully.

I *assume* this is because the *update* function runs AFTER the validation and this is why it isn't working?

Because of this I thought about doing the update in the validation function such as:

```
function my_acf_validate_value( $valid, $value, $field, $input ){

    // bail early if value is already invalid
    if( !$valid ) {
        return $valid;
    }

    // Some code...

    // Return error here?
    return $valid;

}

add_filter('acf/validate_value/key=field_5c121023e119f', 'my_acf_validate_value', 10, 4);
```

...but I don't seem to have access to the `$post_id` here, nor does this seem like the best way to handle it?

Is there a way to handle this better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump` to see what data you have within the function - either in one of the existing function attributes, or by using `get_the_ID()` or `global $post;` to access the current Post object. Beware when trying to manipulate the Post object here, though.

Comment: Here's my code example: https://github.com/markhowellsmead/helpers/wiki/WordPress---Advanced-Custom-Fields#user-email-validation